# Hotspot and Position automatically toggles off

Tags: gps, wifi-hotspot, internet, android-11

I'm on a POCO phone M4 pro 5G, running MIUI Global 12.5.8 Android 11 RP1A 200720.01

Sometime I face this annoying problem which apparently no-one experencied on the internet.
If I'm sharing my connection via WI-FI Hotspot, at a point it may stop working as the button turns off. This may happen once or twice every week randomly (not linked to battery saving mode).
Once the hotspot button toggled off, I coudn't get toggle it on again not even by restarting my phone. As soon as I touch it, it toggles off again. This problem may go away by itselfs in a matter of minutes or hours.
I've never notice before but tonight this thing happenend and I got an error saying my GPS wasn't on anymore. When checking the position button it was toggled off as the hotspot one. I coundn't get back neither of them.
After 30 mins without any restart they started to work again.

What could be the problem... and the solution?
Thanks

Comment: When the issue occurs, have you tried to access `adb logcat` to see if any relevant messages appear? Also does the device feel excessively warm, i.e. thermal throttle?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Actually I didn't. I don't have any clue about that.

Comment: I'm afraid that's a hardware defect

Comment: Are you stationary when this occurring or moving around from one hotspot area to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to try such as:

Enabling and disabling Airplane mode to refresh your connections.

Change your AP Band from 2.4GHz to 5GHz or vice versa.

Do you have an option in your phone to turn off your Hotspot automatically, which may be affecting you if your devices/apps are slow to respond.  If so go into Settings,Wi-Fi & Network > Hotspot & tethering > Wi-Fi hotspot and then disable "Turn off Hotspot Automatically"

I personally tend to wonder if your problem is related to 5G, do you have access to a 4G sim to test in your device to see if it makes any difference.